# PhpStorm 2016.2.1 Typescript formatting remove space around colon

Tags: phpstorm

Updated today to PhpStorm 2016.2.1

All of a sudden my formatting in my TS files are not correct according to my TSLint rules.

```
"typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      },
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ]
```

[image]

In `Editor > Code Style > Typescript` there is no example nor rule to remove the space after a type assertion.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `In Editor > Code Style > Typescript` there is no example nor rule to remove the space after a type assertion.

Well .. I clearly see it in PhpStorm 2016.2.1 (*the option to remove those 2 spaces as pointed by arrows on your screenshot*). I'm not a TypeScript person myself (at all) .. so maybe it would not affect your code .. but for me it looks like the right option.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript`
2. `Spaces | Other | After type reference colon ':'`

[image]

Comment: Omg. How did I miss that one. Thank you.